# Getting data from csv

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, csv

I am getting some extra data frommy csv fields like "('value',)". How can I remove this from my value. I am Searching from yesterday but nothing worked for me. please help me. Thanks in advance.

> My model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class CSVReader(models.Model):
    Run = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    Model = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    Odometer = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    VIN = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    BidType = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    Ammount = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    BuyerName = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)


class UploadFile(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='csv_files')
```

> My view

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, re
import csv
import string

from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import CSVReader, UploadFile


def CSV(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            up = UploadFile.objects.create()
            up.upload = request.FILES['upload']
            up.save()

            path='C:\data_ZXcwWnf.csv'

            remove = "'(),"
            with open(path, 'rb') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                for row in reader:


                    c= CSVReader.objects.create()

                    if row[1]!='':
                        c.Run = row[1].replace("('", '').split("')"),
                        temp = row[1].replace("('", '').split("')"),
                        print temp

                    if row[2] != '':
                        c.Model = row[2].replace(remove,"_"),

                    if row[3] != '':
                        c.Name = row[3].replace(remove,"_"),

                    if row[4] != '':
                        c.Odometer = row[4].replace(remove,"_"),

                    if row[5] != '':
                        c.VIN = row[5].replace(remove,"_"),

                    if row[6] != '':
                        c.BidType = row[6].replace(remove,"_"),

                    if row[7] != '':
                        c.Ammount = row[7].replace(remove,"_"),

                    if row[8] != '':
                        c.BuyerName = row[8].replace(remove,"_")

                    print c.Run, c.Model

                    c.save()

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            print form.errors
            print request.FILES
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/CSV_app/index/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm(UploadFile)
        return render(request, 'CSV_app/index.html', {'form': form})
```

> My Output is:

```
    (['Run#'],)
(['Run#'],) ('Model',)
(['   23-182'],)
(['   23-182'],) ('2013',)
None None
None None
(['   23-183'],)
(['   23-183'],) ('2013',)
None None
None None
(['   23-185'],)
(['   23-185'],) ('2013',)
None None
(['   23-186'],)
(['   23-186'],) ('2013',)
None None
(['   23-187'],)
(['   23-187'],) ('2013',)
```

Comment: Can you add your input CSV file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace your view with:

```
                if row[1]!='':
                    c.Run = row[1]
                    temp = row[1]
                    print temp

                if row[2] != '':
                    c.Model = row[2]

                if row[3] != '':
                    c.Name = row[3]

                if row[4] != '':
                    c.Odometer = row[4]

                if row[5] != '':
                    c.VIN = row[5]

                if row[6] != '':
                    c.BidType = row[6]

                if row[7] != '':
                    c.Ammount = row[7]

                if row[8] != '':
                    c.BuyerName = row[8]
```

Answer (score 1):

This Code:

```
c.Run = row[1].replace("('", '').split("')"),
temp = row[1].replace("('", '').split("')"),
```

> Replace with:

```
c.Run = row[1]
temp = row[1]
```

Now it works fine.